# Lagrange's Theorem proof not using cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups

I'm trying to work out the proof of Lagrange's theorem on my own (which I learned as the order of an element divides the order of the group, but I know it's equivalently about subgroups and is usually presented that way), but my abstract algebra's a bit rusty and I think I've made a wrong assumption about the element order and equivalencies. This is what I have:

For $g\in G$, assume $|g| = k$, $|G| = n$. By contradiction, let $k \nmid n$. We know that $g^k = e$ $\implies$ $g_{1} g_{2}\dots  g_{k} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}.$ This implies that $k \equiv 1\pmod{n}$, which is a contradiction as $k\nmid n$.

What's wrong with this? I understand most of the proofs rely on cosets are are a little more complex, but on first glance I don't get why Lagrange's theorem couldn't be proven really directly.

Edit: this is for the abelian subcase. Sorry for not specifying!

Comment: What are $g_1, g_2.\cdots g_k$?

Comment: Lagrange's theorem is a statement about the order of a subgroup of a finite group, so I'm not sure how you get away from arguments involving the subgroup and its cosets (partitioning the group into equal-sized subsets). It's a *corollary* of Lagrange's theorem that every element must have order that divides the order of the group because the element generates a subgroup.

Comment: How are you stating Lagrange's theorem without cosets?

Comment: @CyclotomicField: you can state it as the claim that the order of a subgroup divides the order of the group, without also saying that the quotient of those two orders counts the number of cosets. The OP wants an even further special case of this, concerning only the order of an element.

Comment: Maybe the way it's been presented to me then was actually a corollary that would be expanded later into the full theorem when cosets are taught, which would make the most sense since what I know as Lagrange's theorem is considerably simpler than what I see as the general theorem online.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a proof without cosets. It is essentially Cayley's theorem. It uses the language of permutations and cycles. This should be studied before abstract group theory.

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $g\in G$. Let $f$ denote the map $G\to G$ given by $f:x\mapsto xg$. This is a bijection on $G$ (as $xg=yg$ iff $x=y$) so induces a permutation $\sigma$ on $G$.

What is the cycle type of $\sigma$? If $x\in G$ then $x,xg,xg^2,\dots,xg^{n-1}$ are all distinct, where $g$ has order $n$, but $xg^n=x$. Thus $(x,xg,xg^2,\dots,xg^{n-1})$ is a cycle of $\sigma$. Thus $\sigma$ is a product of disjoint cycles, each of length $n$, so $|G|/n$ many cycles. In particular, $n\mid |G|$.

(If you want Lagrange's theorem itself, one can take the union of orbits of all elements of $H$ of the maps above. This is cheating, as the orbits are just the cosets. But the same is true above, since you are actually just taking left cosets of $\langle g\rangle$.)

Comment: I would not consider this a proof "without cosets" since, as you say, you are exactly considering the cosets of $\langle g \rangle$. It may be easier to understand than the general coset argument, though.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I wrote it down in the easiest way possible. I guess you can proceed entirely abstractly from the map $f$. If $X$ is a finite set and $f$ is a map on $X$ such that all powers of $f$ are fixed-point-free or the identity, then all points of $X$ "look the same". I cannot see yet how you deduce that the order of the function divides $|X|$, but maybe it can be done just using tools from combinatorics without cosets. Or perhaps eigenvalues of the permutation matrix?

Answer (score 2):

For a finite abelian group $A$ we can prove that every $a \in A$ has order dividing $|A|$ without cosets as follows. Let $n = |A|$ and let $a_1, \dots, a_n$ be an enumeration of the elements of $A$. For any $a \in A$, $a a_1, \dots, a a_n$ is also an enumeration of the elements of $A$, because multiplication by $a$ is a bijection. So, by commutativity,

$$\prod_{i=1}^n a_i = \prod_{i=1}^n a a_i = a^n \prod_{i=1}^n a_i$$

and dividing both sides by $\prod_{i=1}^n a_i$ gives $a^n = e$ as desired.

For a nonabelian group I'm not aware of any way to do it without cosets.

I don't understand your argument because I don't know what the $g_i$ are.

Comment: Oh sorry! That's my bad, I should have specified this was for abelian groups. By $g_i$, I just meant the multiples of the element g until it equals the identity e mod n. It wasn't really necessary for me to write it, it just helps me to visualize it a little more.

Comment: @threebluepens: I still don't understand what you mean. Can you write down a more precise definition?

Comment: So for example in the group of the integers mod 6,  since the elements 2 has order 3, I would "expand" that by writing $(2+2+2) \equiv 0\;mod\;6$. That's all I mean, the expansion of the multiples of the group under the group operation $*$. Like I said it's not necessary to my proof, it's just there to help me visualize.

Comment: Okay. But then what do you mean by "$\bmod n$"? And where does the implication that $k \equiv 1 \bmod n$ come from?

Comment: I mean it's the identity when taken modulo n, the group order. And that implication of $k \equiv 1$ is where I believe I was going wrong, I was jumping from equality to equivalency where I shouldn't have been.

Comment: But $g_1, \dots g_k$ are elements of the group. So what does "$\bmod n$" mean? This is an operation you apply to numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If by "not using cosets" you mean without using any property of the cosets but their very set-wise definition (*e.g.* that they form a partition of $G$, that $|H|=|aH|$ for every $a\in G$, *etc.*), then Lagrange theorem can be gotten from group action theory, by considering the set $X:=\{aH, a\in G\}$ and the action of $G$ on $X$ by left multiplication. The stabilizer at $aH$ is given by $aHa^{-1}$, and hence the stabilizer at $H$ is given by $H$ itself. By the orbit-stabilizer theorem you get that $|H|$ divides $|G|$.